# How can i change the version of a sub dependancy of a crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I'm trying to build some libraries using the wasm32-unknown-unknown and I get

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
  --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libloading-0.6.7/src/lib.rs:66:20
```

I can build using the wasm32-unknown-emscripten but it is not supported by wasm-pack.

So lets say that I have the following tree:

```
neon_empty
└── neon v0.10.1
    ├── neon-macros v0.10.1 (proc-macro)
    │   ├── quote v1.0.28
    │   │   └── proc-macro2 v1.0.59
    │   │       └── unicode-ident v1.0.9
    │   ├── syn v1.0.109
    │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.59 (*)
    │   │   ├── quote v1.0.28 (*)
    │   │   └── unicode-ident v1.0.9
    │   └── syn-mid v0.5.3
    │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.59 (*)
    │       ├── quote v1.0.28 (*)
    │       └── syn v1.0.109 (*)
    ├── neon-runtime v0.10.1
    │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
    │   ├── libloading v0.6.7                <- I want to change this to 0.7.3
    │   │   └── winapi v0.3.9
    │   └── smallvec v1.10.0
    ├── semver v0.9.0
    │   └── semver-parser v0.7.0
    └── smallvec v1.10.0
    [build-dependencies]
    └── neon-build v0.10.1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't; `0.7.3` is not [semver compatible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#semver-compatibility) with `0.6.7`, and so `neon-runtime` would complain about an incompatible version. You can only update it together with `neon-runtime`, once `neon-runtime` was updated to `libloading v0.7.x`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to fork `neon-runtime`, change the `libloading` version and then patch it in your `Cargo.toml` file:

```ini
[patch.crates-io]
neon-runtime = { path = ".." }
# Or
neon-runtime = { git = ".." }
```

This is because (as @Finomnis pointed out) 0.6.x and 0.7.x are not semver-compatible